# Import a Go DLL in my .NET Core application and instantiate an class from the DLL

Tags: c#, go, .net-core

I have a compiled Go dll that I want to use in my .NET Core application. I found the articles to use go libraries in C# but they only show how to use them statically. I want to be able to instantiate a class from the Go library. Is this possible? If so, can you point me to the right direction?

Unfortunately, I cannot keep everything in one language. The Go library must be imported into C#.

Comment: Probably not without modifying the library.  Pinvoke works for a C api, it doesn't know beans about objects.  So such a library would have to exposed functions to create and destroy the object, and take that object as a function argument in other methods.  In effect, the object reference becomes a handle (IntPtr in C#).

Comment: Compiled go exposes functions in the same way as compiled C code. Anything else you'd have to write yourself, managing pointers in one language or the other.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm headed towards the right direction thanks to both your comments above. https://github.com/johncburns1/Golang-.NET-SharedC